# bash - Selecting random object from an array

Tags: arrays, bash, random

I have a function that selects a random object form an array. I have wrapped the internal *bash* function *RANDOM*, and implemented my function like that:

```
function rand() { echo $[ $RANDOM % $2 + $1 ]; }
function rand_obj() { objs=($@); index=$(rand 0 $#); echo ${objs[$index]} ; }
```

It works just fine, but I would love to learn a way of implementing it without the intermediate array *objs*. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `shift $(( $(rand 1 $#) - 1 )); echo "$1"`?

Comment: @EtanReisner, why do't you put it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does something like this

```
rand_obj() {
    shift $(( $(rand 1 $#) - 1 )); echo "$1"
}
```

do what you want?

The above has problems with arguments that *end* with newlines.

Command Substitution always removes trailing newlines.

To handle that scenario you'd need to stick a dummy character/etc. at the end and remove it at use time. Something like this:

```
rand_obj() {
    shift $(( $(rand 1 $#) - 1 )); echo "$1x"
}
elem=$(rand_obj ... ... ... ... ...)
elem=${elem%x}
```

Answer (score 2):

there are too many ways. here is almost oneliner, but assume you have no space in your strings, and you never touched IFS:

```
echo ${ARRAY[@]} | tr ' ' '\n' | shuf -n1
```

Comment: Thanks, very nice - I've never encountered _shuf_. But i am looking for something that does not involve too many calls

Comment: To take care of spaces, & assuming that there are no newlines in arguments, change `echo ${ARRAY[@]} | tr ' ' '\n'` to `printf "%s\n"  "${ARRAY[@]}"`